# Are older android devices doomed to this explanation of where the options menu exist?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

> If you've developed your application for Android 2.3.x (API level 10) or lower, the contents of your options menu appear at the bottom of the screen when the user presses the Menu button, as shown in figure 1. When opened, the first visible portion is the icon menu, which holds up to six menu items. If your menu includes more than six items, Android places the sixth item and the rest into the overflow menu, which the user can open by selecting More.
>   So adding a dynamic toolbar from appcompat-v7 will not dismiss the use of the menu button on the older phones?

Comment: What does it mean for a device to be doomed to an explanation? If you do not want to use the legacy options menu, don't. Use `appcompat-v7` for an action bar backport, or skip the menu system entirely.

Comment: The creation of a toolbar from v7 does not seem to work. The toolbar menu inflates into the menu button no matter what I do. An application always needs a menu. Do you have an alternate to a menu system? I am developing for older devices and want the app to install smoothly on the new devices too.

Comment: "The creation of a toolbar from v7 does not seem to work" -- if by "from v7", you mean that you are using `appcompat-v7`, that should work for action bar and `Toolbar` backports. If you are having problems with them, ask a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you post a [mcve] and explain in detail what "does not seem to work" means.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935644/v7-widget-toolbar-not-showing-why

Comment: I rephrased this question to try to get other views into this situation. My design is creating a layout by extending relativelayout. The app v7 doesnt seem to promote a toolbar into that context. I know through code i can make this happen. I just dont want to program my self into a dark corner where I have chosen to do one thing that doesnt fit into the guidelines of other functions.